# Создать exe файл из программы

Tags: c#

Добрый день, интересует такой вопрос как создание exe файла из своего же приложения в зависимости от введенных данных в форму, как это лучше реализовать?
Пробую через динамическую компиляцию, но мне кажется-это не решение.
Сразу отмечу, что не пишу вирусы, трояны и спамеры.

Comment: > мне кажется-это не решение

Вы знаете, что надо делать, когда кажется.

Comment: Хм, а зачем вам? Компилятор доступен в рантайме, но неужели вам и правда нужна подобная мощь? Объясните, чего вы хотите добиться, наверняка есть более простой метод.

Comment: я почитал форумы и решил что есть проще вариант, так что сейчас буду думать как его реализовать=)

Comment: @markgenuine, Ваш ответ напомнил старое: "Вчера читал пейджер. Много думал".

Comment: может правильней делать не exe, а bat или ps1 файл с нужными параметрами запуска exe?

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от того, какие нужны exe'шники, если .NET'овские (да-да, они разные), то копай в сторону класса Assembly, если обычные - то стандартные методы изменения exe.

Answer (score 0):

[Хабрахабр: Динамическая компиляция кода в C#](https://habrahabr.ru/post/67431/)

Статья не моя но пример хороший:

> **Hello World**
>   Создаем консольное приложение и напишем следующий код:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace ConsoleCompiler
{
internal class Program
{
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
// Source code для компиляции
string source =
@"
namespace Foo
{
public class Bar
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

Bar.SayHello();
}

public static void SayHello()
{
System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"");
}
}
}
";

// Настройки компиляции

Dictionary providerOptions = new Dictionary
{
{"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"}

};
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);

CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
{OutputAssembly = "D:\Foo.EXE", GenerateExecutable = true};

// Компиляция
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);


// Выводим информацию об ошибках
Console.WriteLine("Number of Errors: {0}", results.Errors.Count);
foreach (CompilerError err in results.Errors)
{
Console.WriteLine("ERROR {0}", err.ErrorText);
}
}
}
}
```

> Первое, на что стоит обратить внимание – это использование двух
>   пространств имен (namespace): Microsoft.CSharp System.CodeDom.Compiler
>   В данных классах и содержится ключ к возможности компиляции. В нашем
>   примере мы указываем что компилировать будем под .NET Framework 3.5, а
>   так же указываем что мы хотим получить на выходе – Foo.exe, с
>   возможностью запуска данного приложения.
>
> **Пример посложнее, используем Linq**
>
> Теперь давайте усложним наш пример, в компилируемый код добавим
>   использование Linq:

```
string source = @"
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Foo
{
public class Bar
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

Bar.SayHello();
}

public static void SayHello()
{
System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"");

System.Console.WriteLine( string.Join("","", Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(n=>n.ToString()).ToArray() ) );

}
}
}";
```

> Чтобы компиляция удалась, необходимо добавить в параметры компиляции
>   ссылку на сборку System.Core.dll
>   compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.Dll");

Comment: Особенно нравится в примере с LINQ нечитабельная вложенность запроса)